# strip html tag from xml using xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

i want to fetch normal text from xml which one field containing html data.i cant put condition on template.pls suggest me any solution.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <workdetail>  
<field name="summaryText1">&lt;UL style="MARGIN-TOP: 0in" type=disc&gt;
&lt;LI style="TEXT-ALIGN: justify;MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" class=MsoNormal&gt;&lt;SPAN style="mso-fareast-font-family: 'timesnewroman'; mso-bidi-font-family: calibri; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-latin; mso-bidi-font-style: italic"&gt;&lt;FONT size=2&gt;Manage the daily activities of the HOD s office.&lt;?xml:namespace prefix = o /&gt;&lt;o:p&gt;&lt;/o:p&gt;&lt;/FONT&gt;&lt;/SPAN&gt;&lt;/LI&gt;
&lt;LI style="MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" class=MsoNormal&gt;&lt;SPAN style="mso-fareast-font-family: 'timesnewroman'; mso-bidi-font-family: calibri; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-latin; mso-bidi-font-style: italic"&gt;&lt;FONT size=2&gt;Handle and manage all communication, correspondence and filing of documents. &lt;o:p&gt;&lt;/o:p&gt;&lt;/FONT&gt;&lt;/SPAN&gt;&lt;/LI&gt;
&lt;LI style="MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0pt" class=MsoNormal&gt;&lt;SPAN style="mso-fareast-font-family: 'timesnewroman'; mso-bidi-font-family: calibri; mso-bidi-theme-font: minor-latin; mso-bidi-font-style: italic"&gt;&lt;FONT size=2&gt;Fix appointments, arrange for meetings, conferences etc.&lt;o:p&gt;&lt;/o:p&gt;&lt;/FONT&gt;&lt;/SPAN&gt;&lt;/LI&gt;
 </workdetail>
```

mu xsl file is as

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output  indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<workdetail>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</workdetail>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*:workdetail">
 <xsl:variable name="text" select="*:field[starts-with(@name,'summaryText1')]"/>
         <xsl:choose>

    <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&lt;')">

        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text, '&lt;')"/>



                <xsl:variable name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&gt;')"/>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>

        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>

    </xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this is returning everything after > tag. can i pass more value in this which will return only text document.

Comment: Consider to post the output you want to create for the XML input sample you have posted. And please tell us which XSLT 2.0 processor you use as for instance some versions of Saxon 9.5 have http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/parse-html which could make the task of parsing HTML easy.

Comment: thanks martin for reply.i am using xslt2.0 processor and saxon9pe.jar to transform. my expected output is                                                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <workdetail> 
 <summaryText1>Manage the daily activities of the HOD s office.,Handle and manage all communication, correspondence and filing of documents.,Fix appointments, arrange for meetings, conferences etc.
</summaryText1>
</workdetail>                                        i just want to remove all html tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Saxon 9.5 PE you should be able to use http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/parse-html:

```
<xsl:template match="workdetail/field[@name = 'summaryText1']">
  <xsl:value-of select="saxon:parse-html(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

where you have

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">...</xsl:stylesheet>
```

declared on the root element of your stylesheet.

If you don't have access to a HTML parser you could try to strip markup with a `replace` and a regular expression but the following is made as a suggestion on how to approach that, the regular expression is not tested thoroughly:

```
<xsl:template match="workdetail/field[@name = 'summaryText1']">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&lt;/?\w+[^&lt;]*&gt;', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: hi martin thanks for reply.one question can i do the same thing with saxon8e or saxonhe free version .is there any other way to do in that.

Comment: I don't think the open source Saxon 9.5 HE has support for that extension function. I don't know which version you refer to with "saxon8e" and you would need to check its documentation yourself whether it has support for that extension function.

Comment: thanku for reply again.yaa i checked that both saxon8e and saxon9.5he showing saxon extension function not available.is there any other way where i can remove all html tag.

Comment: @user1906222, I have edited the answer and provided an attempt to strip tags with a regular expression and the `replace` function.

Comment: thanks martin for your help.finally i am able to get the output. using this.only constrain in that i cant use "&" symbol.that can manage.<xsl:variable name="text" select="*:field[starts-with(@name,'summaryText1')]"/>

            <xsl:variable name="text2" select="replace($text, '&lt;/?\w+[^&lt;]*&gt;', '')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="text3" select="replace($text2, '&amp;nbsp;', '')"/>
   
   <xsl:value-of  select="replace($text3, '&amp;amp;', '')"/>